# I can't migrate dynamically with Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, config, migrate

I am creating a database for each user who has a record. I am able to set this created database via config. But I can't migrate.
The error I encountered is:

Database [5d7acdf5adf6a] not configured.

```
    $user=User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'database'=>uniqid()
    ]);

     Artisan::call('make:database',['dbname'=>$user->database]);
     $this->connectAnother($user->database);

     Artisan::call('migrate',['--database'=>$user->database]);
     dd(Artisan::output());
     error-->Database [5d7acdf5adf6a] not configured.
```

connectAnother is a method I wrote.

```
    public function connectAnother($database){
            \Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
            "database" => $database,
            "username" => "...",
            "password" => "..."
        ]);
    }
```

config/database.php:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

I tried to migrate directly when I changed the database, but got the answer 'Nothing to migrate'

Comment: Is the name of database registered?

Comment: looks like the database was created in mysql

Comment: i think you need to change the `[5d7acdf5adf6a]` to the driver you used. e.g change `[5d7acdf5adf6a]` to `mysql`

Comment: How about assigning a name when making it?

Comment: What I want is to have a database for each user who is actually registered and access their database after login. To do this, I created a unique id when the user registered. I can change the database name on the config, but I have this problem when migrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
 public function connect($database){
    $connection = [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => config('database.connections.mysql.url'),
        'host' => config('database.connections.mysql.host'),
        'port' => config('database.connections.mysql.port'),
        'database' => $database,
        'username' => config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
        'password' => config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ];
    \Config::set("database.connections.{$database}", $connection);
    DB::setDefaultConnection($database);->***The most important place in this line***
```